# UITableViewCell Images Changing after Scrolling Up and Down but TextLabel Text Remain Same (iOS8, Swift)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I'm trying to create an RSS app for practice. So my tableView cell has both textLabel and image. My textLabel's text and image data come from a dictionary stored in Core Data. Some cells have images, and some don't. The initial load of tableView looks fine to me. But when I scroll down and up, cell's images seem to change. The cells' textLabel text doesn't change though.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as NSManagedObject
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.DisclosureIndicator
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("title")!.description

    var image: UIImage?
    if let imageData = object.valueForKey("imageData") as? NSData {
        image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        let itemSize = CGSizeMake(80, 80)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize)
        let imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height)
        image?.drawInRect(imageRect)
        cell.imageView?.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

If the initial tableView loads correctly, that means my Core Data stores my data's mapping correctly. But when scrolling down and up, `configureCell` is being called again since it needs to redraw the cell. `cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("title")!.description` is set correctly again, but not image here. Don't know why it behaves like this. Please give some pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem once and I think it has something to do with the reused cell not being in the default state so sometimes the image you set is being reused. To fix it, I just did an `else` condition on imageData and set the image to a default image if no image was found. I'm sure you could set it to nil here as well.

```
    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath) {
        cell.imageView.image = image
    } else {
        // Default image or nil
        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Calendar")
    }
```

And I wouldn't suggest storing images as raw data in core data, as this can be very inefficient. Instead, download them to your documents directory and store a file name in core data.

Comment: It works like a charm. Also thanks for the image download and storing advice as well. I will explore how to that.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was remove the image from imageView and set image again. It works for me.

```
cell.imageView.image = nil
cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"Calendar")
```